# What is the meaning of this operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, quantum-entanglement, interferometry

In interferometry with coherent light, the final output is differenced detectors. That is,

$\left<N\right> = \left<N_1\right> - \left<N_2\right>$

where $N_i$ is the number operator of that mode.

However, in interferometry with NOON states, the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOON_state#Applications) states

> consider the observable
>
> ```
> A = | N , 0 ⟩ ⟨ 0 , N | + | 0 , N ⟩ ⟨ N , 0 |
> ```
>
> The expectation value of A {\displaystyle A} A for a system in a NOON
>   state switches between +1 and −1 when the phase changes from 0 to $π/N$.

My confusion is with the expression and physical meaning of the operator A. If the NOON state is

$\left|\psi\right> = \frac{\left|N\right>_a\left|0\right>_b+e^{iN\phi}\left|0\right>_a\left|N\right>_b}{\sqrt{2}}$

as taken in the Wikipedia article. Then, because I'm confused about the notation of $A$, there are two possible expressions of $A$ for me. $A_1$ and $A_2$:

$A_1 =  \left|N\right>_a\left|0\right>_b\left<N\right|_a\left<0\right|_b + \left|0\right>_a\left|N\right>_b\left<0\right|_a\left<N\right|_b$,

which I think would be the sum of the number operators on both the output arms of the Interferometer. However, this operators doesn't give the correct result of

$\left<A\right> = \cos 2\phi$

which Wikipedia alludes to in its change of phase from 1 to -1 statement. On the other hand, the expression

$A_2 =  \left|N\right>_a\left|0\right>_b\left<0\right|_a\left<N\right|_b + \left|0\right>_a\left|N\right>_b\left<N\right|_a\left<0\right|_b$

does give the correct answer. However, I don't understand the physical realization of this operator. And if this is the measurement being performed, then [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/0904.0163) paper refers to it as

> If one now carries out a
>   simple measurement scheme in the N-photon detecting analyzer

So, what is this measurement being carried out? Which one is the correct representation, $A_1$ or $A_2$, of $A$ as written by Wikipedia? And what is the physical meaning of this operator?

Comment: Yes $A_2$ is the correct interpretation. Indeed it is essentially the same notation

Comment: Do you know what is being measured then?

Comment: In QM every hermitian operator can _in principle_ be measured. Whether it can be measured is another kettle of fish. If all you want is it's expectation value it seems that measuring the number of particles in a and b is more the enough.